# "npm install" de um .tgz sem conexão com a internet

Tags: npm

Fiz o download usando "npm pack" e obtive o ionic-4.0.6.tgz, agora no PC sem conexão com a Internet rodei o comando "npm install ionic-4.0.6.tgz" e ele pede conexão com a internet.

Há alguma maneira de instalar totalmente offline?

Comment: Olha, se você esta tentando fazer um download obviamente precisa de internet....

Comment: [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43064107/how-to-install-npm-package-while-offline) similar.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme o https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install é possivel sim usar NPM com pacotes locais, comandos suportados:

```
npm install (sem argumentos)
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<tag>
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<version>
npm install [<@scope>/]<name>@<version range>
npm install <git-host>:<git-user>/<repo-name>
npm install <git repo url>
npm install <tarball file>
npm install <tarball url>
npm install <folder>
```

O seu caso deve ser o `npm install <tarball file>`, a questão é, se ele esta pedindo internet deve ser por causa de alguma dependência que o pacote `ionic-4.0.6`, lembre-se, TODOS pacotes contém o seu proprio `package.json`, logo pode ser que um pacote a ser instalado dependa de outros pacotes.

Só pra constar, `ionic-4.0.6.tgz` deve ser apontado como caminho absoluto ou deve ir na pasta raiz do projeto, por exemplo:

```
./projeto
  ├─── ./packages.json
  ├─── ./ionic-4.0.6.tgz
  └─── ./node_modules
```

Se estiver assim então navegue até a pasta "projeto" (exemplo apenas) com `cd` e depois execute o comando `npm install ionic-4.0.6.tgz`, agora se o pacote estiver em outra pasta você deve apontar o caminho absoluto, por exemplo:

```
cd projeto
npm install c:\projetos\outro_projeto_de_onde_copiará_os_pacotes\ionic-4.0.6.tgz
```

Note que se você já possui o "cliente" (comando de linha) do Ionic, você não precisa instalar as coisas manualmente, basta executar um destes 3 comandos:

1. Cria um app vazio (geralmente uso esse `:)` ):

   ```
   ionic start <nome do projeto> blank
   ```
2. Cria um app com abas:

   ```
   ionic start <nome do projeto> tabs
   ```
3. Cria um app com sidemenu:

   ```
   ionic start <nome do projeto> sidemenu
   ```

> Troque `<nome do projeto>` pelo nome da pasta que deseja nomear para o projeto

Pois geralmente na instalação global do ionic (se já tiver instalado) você já tem todas dependências salvas em um tipo de cache em seu computador, ou seja, é provável que precise de internet para isto.

Comment: Então, eu tentei com o .tgz na raiz e com caminho absoluto, ambos geram erros alegando não poder conectar com a internet. Na verdade não possuo nada instalado na máquina do Ionic e baixei esse .tgz que contém todas as dependências

Comment: caro @MayconWSoler vc leu a minha resposta inteira? Pode ser que o ionic dependa de outras coisas, vc tem o ionic instalado globalmente para usa-lo via linha de comando e assim ter em cache? Pq até aonde sei esse é o caminho recomendado e "oficial" de usar o IONIC. Vc instala ele globalmente e nunca mais precisará instalar ele novamente, pode criar 1000 projetos a partir do comando `ionic start <nome do projeto>`

Comment: Sim, li toda a resposta @GuilhermeNascimento, o problema está exatamente ai, não possuo global e gostaria de instalar nessa máquina, trazendo o arquivo de uma máquina com acesso à internet, ou seja. trabalhar em "modo offline". Esta máquina que me refiro não possuo acesso nenhum com a internet

Comment: @MayconWSoler tudo vem, vou ver o que é possivel e necessário para instalar o ionic globalmente em uma maquina totalmente offline. Ao menos tem acesso a pen-drives né?

Comment: Sim, e possuo acesso de Administrador local da máquina, muito obrigado!